# How to split data into 2 rows based on a character?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
      col1  col2   col3  col4
row1  'a'    'b'    'c'   'd\ne'
row2 'f\ng' 'h\ni' 'j\nk' 'l\nm'
row3 'n'    'o'    'p'     'q'
row4 'r'    's'    't'     'u'
```

I want to split the data of the row into 2 separate rows based on a character/when character count of the character is more than 4 in a given row.

In this case split data based on : '\n', and when the count of this character row-wise > 3.

Output :

```
          col1  col2   col3  col4
    row1  'a'     'b'    'c'   'd\ne'
    row2  'f'     'h'    'j'    'l'
    row3  'g'     'i'    'k'    'm'
    row4  'n'     'o'    'p'    'q'
    row5  'r'     's'    't'    'u'
```

How can i do this ?

Code to identify row with '\n' characters.

```
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    if '\n' in df.iloc[row,0]:
        if (''.join(df.iloc[row]).count('\n'))>3:
            print(row)
```

This can use a little refinement maybe doing all this in a single line ?

Can i somehow use vstack with splitting data frame based on '\n' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to split the row when all values contain a `\n`:

```
# identify \n
m = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('\n'))

# split rows having \n in all columns
df.update(df[m.all(axis=1)].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n')))

# create new row(s)
df = df.explode(list(df), ignore_index=True)

# update the index
df.index = 'row' + (df.index+1).astype(str)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     col1 col2 col3  col4
row1    a    b    c  d\ne
row2    f    h    j     l
row3    g    i    k     m
row4    n    o    p     q
row5    r    s    t     u
```

Comment: Solved, This is exactly it.

Comment: I  get this error in during updating :- "Cannot re-index on duplicate axis" ,how do i solve this ?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that triggers this error? And indicate the line of code which triggers it? Do you originally have duplicated indices in the index?

Comment: I tried resetting the index before sending it [df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) ,but that didn't help...  The update command is what is causing the error.

Comment: You can't use `inplace` in this context. Remove it.

Comment: ok, still the same.

Comment: Can we use lag to add an empty row and then overwrite to this row ?

Comment: Then try to replace the `update` line with: `df[m.all(axis=1)] = df[m.all(axis=1)].apply(...)`

Comment: Wow, this worked i reset the index before sending the data too. Thanks !!!!!